# How do I install Tastypie for Django?

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-apps

I am following the [instructions](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation) to install Tastypie for Django and I am stuck somewhere between step 2 and 3. I successfully ran "sudo pip install django-tastypie" however, I don't know where the "tastypie" directory is that I am supposed to use for the symlink.

Comment: You are not doing such thing using symlinks, this is handled by PYTHONPATH variable. If you installed it properly,mother only thing to use it in your code is to just import it as any other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your distro and version of Python. Most likely the folder you are looking for is located in the `site-packages` subfolder under your python home folder.

To see the exact location try running:

```
python -m site
```

For more details also try:

```
python -m site --help
```

And you can get only the `sys.path` by running:

```
python -c "import sys; print ('\n').join(sys.path)"
```

Comment: I had originally checked the site-packages directory but had not seen tastypie. I went wrong by running "sudo pip install django-tastypie" instead of "pip install django-tastyie". The install did not go to my virtualenv. That's what I get for blindly following directions and not using my brain; :). Many thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware that `pip` could run as a non-root user. Always installed all the modules system-wide, but looks like with pip a user can have them installed in the user-site dir. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Tastypie has already been added to your pythonpath. To check, type python in your command line and then type import tastypie. if you do not see an error, you're good.

Just add tastypie to your installed apps and use it with django.

Answer (score 1):

Install tastypie via pip:

```
sudo pip install django-tastypie &&
sudo pip install djangorestframework
```

Add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'tastypie',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Comment: django-rest-framework and django-tastypei are independent API frameworks. Why did you require both at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `easy_install django-tastypie`, if using `virtualenv`.